# unable to ssh via usb cable

Tags: usb, ssh, pi-zero-w

1. Installed fresh raspberry pi OS with default settings
2. created empty ssh file in root folder
3. in config.txt commented original dtoverlay and did put `dtoverlay=dwc2`
4. cmdline.txt did put `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` after `rootwait`
5. Connect USB to USB port (not power)
6. Windows does the sound when some device is connected
7. Wait about 2 mins

when I do ssh via putty

```
Unable to open connection to raspberrypi.local Host does not exist
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resolved this.
If your PI recognised as a COM port device, you will need to install extra drivers

1. RNDIS Driver
2. Bonjour Service (Apple Inc.)

Then your PI will be recognised a network device and then ssh should start to work

more: https://www.factoryforward.com/pi-zero-w-headless-setup-windows10-rndis-driver-issue-resolved/

Answer (score -1):

I noticed you said the usb was not the power-port. If you connect the usb-c power-port it can provide power and data. Maybe an interesting solution for you?

If you like to have an introduction to this, watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3qn1nqw-Gw this is focussed on iPad, but it should work with Windows in a similar way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).